# Trying to calculate the number of attributes/properties an object has. Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I've looked online and at previous answers on here but I still can't quite grasp how to use:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Although I'm not sure it's exactly what I want.

Lets say for example I have an object called man:

```
this.name = "steve"
this.age = 80
this.lives = "london"
this.children = 5
```

How can I easily determine that the man object has 4 properties. I don't need the values of the properties, just the number of them. Thanks.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).length` should work

Comment: You already have the answer - `Object.keys(this).length`

Comment: Oh, 'this' is what I am missing

Comment: @user3066820 what blanks?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your man object will be as below:

```
man = {
    name: 'steve',
    age: 80,
    lives: 'london',
    children: 5
}
```

Now, to get the number of properties of man object, you should do:

```
 alert(Object.keys(man).length); //will alert 4
```

Comment: Ah you are right! I was writing man.keys(this).length.
I didn't realise I didn't replace Object. Thanks!

Comment: make sure you accept answers if they work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count only the object's own attributes try this:

```
var count = 0
for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        count++;
    }
}
alert(count);
```